# Libre/Open Office Calc: Copy&Paste without formatting

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

As described in [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=65442) when doing copy and past in `Office Calc`, all the formatting is moved from the source cell to the target cell too. Including Frames and cell background color.

This mentioned thread is 10 years old, maybe there is now a workaround.

I'm looking for a way of either **lock the format settings of a cell** or to do an **one click action to insert without destroying the layout** of my spread sheet.

The in the thread suggested solution is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> which opens an additional context menu where you can select what to insert. I would like to have a permanent option.

Comment: I think you can't make the settings you choose in the window that appears when you press Ctrl+Shift+V permanent. But it does last for the current session.

Comment: jap, at least it does.

Answer (score 1):

A half way workaround at least is to use <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit Cell's content.

After hitting it a cursor in the cell and you can insert every other cell content or html from the browser into it without being asked in a context menu. The format stays. Still open how to do it with more than one cell or copy&past from cell to cell in the Office.